# Schema for tracking SQL Server table updates

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I have a set of 16 SQL Server tables, which get updated constantly from a Web UI. I need to track every change happening to these tables and call a separate system every 10 minutes sending each inserted or updated row through a Windows service.

I can duplicate the schema and create another set of 16 similar tables to track changes in the original set. There will be triggers that insert a new row into tracking tables (plus ins/upd flag, timestamp etc fields) every time a corresponding source table is modified.

I am wondering is there any better way I can do this using 1 (or few) common tables that can hold data from multiple tables? Something that does not force me to maintain a duplicate set of tracking tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Enterprise Edition, [Change Data Capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb522489(v=SQL.105).aspx) is an option which is available to you.

Other editions have [Change Tracking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx), which doesn't track history but can get you the net changes.

Comparison: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc280519(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this should work perfectly. But just in case DBA's do not allow enabling CDC for whatever reasons, what would be the best way to manage tracking manually without duplicating every table?

Comment: Talk to your DBAs first. The links I provided are **built-in** methods of tracking changes and should be the path of least resistance. They'd better have some *very* good reasons to refuse to use a SQL Server feature which does what you need and significantly reduces overhead & duplication of work/data.